# Pass dropbox value to a HttpGet action submit button click?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Basically I'm trying to pass the value of my dropbox to a get action.
The submit-button re-directs to the correct action , but what is the correct way to add the value of the dropbox  with the re-direction?

My view:

```
 @model TrackerModel
     @using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Get, new { ???}))
     {
     <div>
        <strong>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.CustomerName)</strong>
         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerName, new { type = "hidden", @class = "customer-picker" })
     </div>
     <button class="styledbutton" onclick="window.location.href='/Tracker/Index'">Cancel</button>
     <button type="submit" value="submit" id="selectCustomer-button" class="styledbutton">Submit</button>
 }
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult MyAction(IPrincipal user, Tracker model)
```

Customer-picker

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
CustomerPicker();
```

});

function CustomerPicker() {

```
$('.customer-picker').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select customer',
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    ajax: { // instead of writing the function to execute the request we use Select2's convenient helper
        url: '/JsonData/GetCustomers',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (term) {
            return {
                query: term // search term
            };
        },
        results: function (data) { // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
            // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to alter remote JSON data
            return { results: data };
        }
    },
    formatResult: function (data) {
        return data;
    },
    formatSelection: function (data) {
        return data;
    }
});
```

}

I was expecting the value to be within my `Tracker` model parameter in the action, but this returns nulls. Also I'm not sure what to place in the "new" parameter in the form tag?

I also tried the following but all I get returning to the controller is text:"".

```
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerName, new { type = "hidden", @id = "selectedCustomer", @class = "customer-picker" })

     <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#Form1").submit(function (e) {
        alert("boo");
        e.preventDefault();
        var selectCustValue = $("#selectedCustomer").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/CalibrationViewer/SentMultipleCalsToCustomer',
            data: { text: selectCustValue }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: where is dropbox ????

Comment: Apologies, the TextBoxfor is acting as a dropbox, using a jquery function...I was hoping I could maybe add an Id to the textbox and somehow get it's value.

Comment: then try giving it a name and get its value on get controller with name

Comment: You mean within the textboxfor tag something like, new{ @name="selectedcustomer"}  ..... and add string selectedcustomer as a parameter in the Get action ?

Comment: no joy, string selectedCustomer parameter on the Get action is null when submit button clicked ....... would changing the button tag to an input tag make any difference ?

Comment: just take input type button and submit form with jquery

Comment: I should be able to pass the value with out resorting to jQuery no ? can you point me in the direction of an example ?

Comment: can you post the code..i want to see how textboxfor is acting as dropbox..

Comment: done, I would rather not interfere with this jquery as it's used else where in the program.

Comment: check latest edit with jquery

Comment: What is the actual html rendered by `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerName`? It should be `<input name="CustomerName" ...`

Comment: A textbox with "select Customer" as the place holder, click in it and a blank box appears for user to begin typing and a mgs "Please enter 1 more characters" underneath, customer names appear as user types...

Comment: No, I mean the actual html (right click in the browser and view the source)

Comment: Apologies....  <input class="customer-picker" id="selectedCustomer" name="CustomerName" type="hidden" value="" />

Comment: It's the correct name attribute so it should post back. Why are you using `FormMethod.Get` rather than `Post` and what is the parameter `IPrincipal user` (are you using a custom model binder?)

Comment: Because I want to send the value to a Get action, That action will than use the info as a search parameter , to return a list. Iprincipal, on doing an F12 = Interface , gets the identity of the current principal (originally not my project so still figuring some stuff out), I believe this program is using a custom model blinder.

Answer (score 0):

OK got it,

```
   var selectCustValue = $("#s2id_CustomerName span").text();
```

Found another piece of code the used the customer-picker and the javascript associated with view used the above.

I viewed the page source and it still show's both id and name as CustomerName, it has something to do with the "Select 2" helper.

I may get slated for marking this as the answer, considering I should have figured it out earlier, but there you have it !