# Why won't code return the correct view with added viewModelList

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Long story short,
I'm sending a piece of data to a Get action as a parameter.
This parameter will be used in the search parameter of a list I wish to display using the view that will return from the Get action.
The data is sent to the get action , but for some reason the view remains the same in the application.
The code jumps to the view but does not render it ?

Controller - "Get" action which receives the text parameter via jquery in another view.

```
       [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SentMultipleCalsToCustomer(IPrincipal user, string text)
   {
        int totalRecords;

        IList<Calibration> calibrationList;

        //user selected value
        string customer = text;

        //get user name
        LtsUser ltsUser = _ltsUserRepo.GetUser(user.Identity.Name);

        // access the required data from the calibration repository
        calibrationList = _calRepo.GetAllFinishedCalibrations(customer, out totalRecords);

        //map the list
        var customerViewList = Mapper.Map<IList<Calibration>, IList<TrackerModel>>(calibrationList);

        IList<TrackerModel> CalList = customerViewList;
        //return the list to the view
        return View("SentMultipleCalsToCustomer", CalList);

    }
```

View which selects customer:

```
  @using InstrumentTracker.ViewModels.TrackerModels;
  @using InstrumentTracker.CustomHelpers
  @using InstrumentTracker.Common.Enums
  @using System

  @model TrackerModel

 @{
   ViewBag.Title = "CustomerSelected";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  }

 <h2 style="position:relative; left:20%;">Select Customer</h2>

 <fieldset id="customerSelect-fieldset">
<legend>Customer to send Finished Calibrations to :</legend>

<br />

@* shows a filter for calibrations for a specific customer, this filter is only shown for lts users *@

 @using (Html.BeginForm("SentMultipleCalsToCustomer", "CalibrationViewer", FormMethod.Get, new {         @id = "Form1" }))
    {
    <div>
        <strong>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.CustomerName)</strong>
         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerName, new { type = "hidden", @class = "customer-picker"           })
    </div>

      <button type="submit" value="submit" id="CustomerSubmit" class="styledbutton" style="float:right; margin-right:2%; margin-top:5%;">Submit</button>
 }
    <button class="styledbutton" style="float:right; margin-top:5%;"   onclick="window.location.href='/Tracker/Index'">Cancel</button>


 </fieldset>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
    $("#Form1").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selectCustValue = $("#s2id_CustomerName span").text();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/CalibrationViewer/SentMultipleCalsToCustomer',
            data: { user:null, text: selectCustValue }
        });
    });
   });
 </script>
```

View I want to render:

```
  @using InstrumentTracker.ViewModels.TrackerModels
  @using InstrumentTracker.ViewModels.CalibrationViewerModels
  @using MvcPaging
  @using SquishIt.Framework

  @model IList<TrackerModel>
  @{

   ViewBag.Title = "SentMultipleCalsToCustomer";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

   AjaxOptions ajaxOpts = new AjaxOptions
    {
    UpdateTargetId = "all-calibrations-grid",
    HttpMethod = "Post"
   };
   }

  <h2 id="trackerHeading">Sent Multiple Calibrations to one Customer</h2>


  <div id="tabs" class="main">


 <div id="tabs-1" style="position:relative; left:-10%;">
    <div>
        <h3>List of @Model.Count() Finished Calibrations to be Sent out Today -     @DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString()</h3>
    </div>


  <table id="all-calibrations" class="grid tracker-grid" style="width:50%">
  <colgroup>
    <col class="workno-data" style="width:22%">
    <col class="equipmentId-data" style="width:22%">
    <col class="equipmentDesc-data" style="width:22%">
  </colgroup>

  <thead>

    <tr>
        <th>Work<br />No.</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Description</th>

        @if (this.User.IsInRole("LTS User Passive"))
        {
            <th>Customer</th>
        }
    </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
    @for (int index = 0; index < Model.Count(); index++)
    {

        <tr>

            @* The work number is a link to the calibration the work no. represents *@
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("WN–" + @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.ElementAt(index).Id),   "Index", "CalibrationViewer", new { id = Model.ElementAt(index).Id }, null)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.ElementAt(index).EquipmentID)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.ElementAt(index).EquipmentDescription)</td>
            @* once again only the lts user sees the customer column data *@
            @if (this.User.IsInRole("LTS User Passive"))
            {
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.ElementAt(index).CustomerName)</td>
            }
        </tr>  
     }
    </tbody>  
   </table>

  </div>



 @Html.Raw(Bundle.JavaScript()
.Add("~/Scripts/Tracker/Tracker.js")
.Add("~/Scripts/Tracker/StatusHelp.js")
.Add("~/Scripts/CalibrationViewer/ReceivedByLtsFromCustomer.js")
.Add("~/Scripts/CalibrationViewer/WorkFlowOption.js")
.Render("~/Scripts/trackercombined_#.js")

 )
```

The problem is not with the view, as I deleted all the code in it and run program again and it still doesn't rendered.

The problem has to be with the jquery used to direct to the Action.
I tired commenting out the url line in the ajax code and using the following on submit btn click,

```
   onclick="window.location.href='/CalibrationViewer/SentMultipleCalsToCustomer'"
```

The code did try redirect to the correct view but because the customerName was null, an error returned !

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen here?  You call the action with ajax but then don't do anything with the view it returns.  Is it not hitting your action at all?  Any javascript errors?

Comment: I am expecting my SentMultipleCalsToCustomer view to render as the last line of the same named action suggests. I placed a break point on the Action and it does indeed run through it and even runs through the code for the view , but simply won't navigate to the view ??? no javascript errors that I can see.... removed all the code from the view and just entered some text, still nothing.... Tried naming a different view in the Return statement, again nothing !.... would ajax call from the previous action prevent page navigation  in the controller ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just need it to redirect you to a different page.  You don't need ajax at all for that.  You can do it this way:

```
$(function () {
    $("#Form1").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selectCustValue = $("#s2id_CustomerName span").text();
        window.location.href = "/CalibrationViewer/SentMultipleCalsToCustomer?text=" + selectCustValue;
    });
});
```

I am almost certain there is a better (and simpler) way to do what you are trying to here, but since you did not provide your HTML I cannot even begin to guess if that is true or not.

Comment: yep, but if what he needs to do is just redirect, why use jquery??? why not just post using the form submit??? (and change the [HttpGet] to  [HttpPost] if needed)

Comment: @EricGS I agree.  If all he needs to do is just redirect, javascript is completely unnecessary.  However without knowing what his HTML looks like and what he can change, this may be a hack to get around that.  I don't know what he's dealing with so I figure this should at least get something working without making too many assumptions about his situation.

Comment: Ok , your nearly there, the code provided returns a null for text.I had a previous problem with the CustomerName text/dropdown box...ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25380135/pass-dropbox-value-to-a-httpget-action-submit-button-click .... I'll post code of view I want to render.

Comment: Apologies, a couple of cleans, re-builds and a clear of history and the above answer worked. Appreciate all input.

Comment: gre8, but i still think u don't need any javascript/jquery, if i understand your code, CustomerName textBox is what you need to send to the controler as "text" field??? if that is correct, just delete all js, and change the controller "text" property to "CustomerName"

Answer (score 0):

what are you doing whit the returned data (view) from your ajax? shuld u set the targget to place that view?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#Form1").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selectCustValue = $("#s2id_CustomerName span").text();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/CalibrationViewer/SentMultipleCalsToCustomer",
            data: { user: null, text: selectCustValue },
            success: function (data) {
                    $('#divTargetOrAny').html(data);
                }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The returned data is used as a search parameter in the SentMultipleCalsToCustomer Action. Jquery is not my strong suit. I thought ajax would simply send the selectCustValue to the SentMultipleCalsToCustomer action and that action would use it like it would any other type of parameter .... but the view dose not change despite the program going through the SentMultipleCalsToCustomer view code ?  where would id=divTargetOrAny be located ??

Comment: the view is being returned to you ajax call, then u should put that view in the part of the page you what, replace or append or any u need, as an example if u have the content to replace on a <div id="divTargetOrAny"> </div> on succes replace the html data ass show in the answer code. Are you trying to render a full new page??? or just a part of it??? if you are returning a new full page, ajax may not be what you need, if u are trying to update a part of that view, u may need to return the view as a partial view instead a full view

Comment: this may help, not shure how diferent is mvc3 to mvc4 but... http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m5-data-ii&mode=live&clip=0&course=mvc4-building    search for the ajax helper

Comment: pd: the view is not changing because you are not using the retrieved data (view). divTargetOrAny is the id or any selector to where u need to load your data